# How to write bash script to test if program crashes?

Tags: bash, process

I have a program x which sometimes crashes on certain input files.

How do I write a bash script that returns the following?

- 0 if the program x terminates fine or runs for longer than 1/20th of a second
- 1 if the program x segfaults

Note that the program will segfault or run forever, so I need to stop it somehow with the script. can you show me please

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the programs when they do not terminate correctly return 0.  That information can be gleaned from the bash variable `$?`.  So, after you run the program, check if `$?` is 0.  If it is, the program ran successfully.  Otherwise, there was a problem.

This is, of course, assuming that the program is following proper conventions.

Comment: The program will segfault or run forever, so I need to stop it somehow with the script. can you show me please

Comment: You can use `timeout` to stop a program after n seconds.

Answer (score 1):

echo $? should let you know whether or not the program succeeded.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Executing-Commands-with-bash/1/